# Extracting only date from datetime field (mysql) and assigning it to php variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am unable to assign only date to a php variable from `datetime` field of a MySQL table. I am using **PHP 4**, I know how to do it in PHP 5.

Can someone help as to what is missing from the below php code.

```
$dc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM INVHDR WHERE Invdate BETWEEN '2011-04-01' AND '2012-03-31'");
while ($dc2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($dc)) {
    $invno      = $dc2['Invno']; // Here Invno is a datetime field type
    $invdat3    = $dc2['Invdate'];
    $date_array = explode("-", $invdat3);
    $invdat     = sprintf('%02d/%02d/%4d', $date_array[2], $date_array[1], $date_array[0]);
}
```

Comment: msql_* is been deprecated hope u know that use pdo indtead

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO, he's using PHP 4. PDO was not present until PHP >= 5.1

Comment: for safer side i am asking not use in future.

Comment: Very easy. Just refer this :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Is this a PHP problem or an SQL problem?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you just want to *display* the date portion, you could use the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```php
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2012-12-24 12:13:14")->format("d/m/Y");
# 24/12/2012
```

Comment: This works, but this isn't the answer. He should just be using the `DATE()` function in the `SELECT` portion of his query.

Comment: I have reasons why he should be displaying/formatting dates in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

There is a link I find extremely useful when it comes to date manipulations:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

one can easily find the solution there:

```
SELECT *, DATE(Invdate) as Inv_date ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Do it directly in MySQL:

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2012-12-24 12:13:14', '%Y/%m/%d')
```

So your query will look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Invdate, '%Y/%m/%d') FROM INVHDR WHERE Invdate BETWEEN '$startdat' AND '$enddat'
```