# Get part of date in php

Tags: php, date

I need to get just the day from a datetime value in php. I get from my database something like '2015-01-01 12:12:12' and I just need '2015-01-01' for adding after it  ' 00:00:00' or ' 23:59:59'.

I tried:

```
  echo $res0['dateInit'];
  $date_day = date('yyyy-mm-dd',$res0['dateInit']);
  $date_init = $date_day . " 00:00:00";
  $date_end = $date_day . " 23:59:59";
  echo $date_init;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $date_end;
```

But I get a wrong value in the second echo. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to repeat the year four times, the month twice and the day twice? This is PHP, not MS Excel - [Format codes for date() in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: no, I just want it one each time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting only date from datetime field (mysql) and assigning it to php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020090/extracting-only-date-from-datetime-field-mysql-and-assigning-it-to-php-variabl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **strtotime**, check the code given below:

```
$date = '2015-01-01 12:12:12';
$day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
$split_date = split(" ",$date);
print "day = $day and $date and $split_date[0]";
```

And the output is

**day = 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-01 12:12:12 and 2015-01-01**

Comment: also if your date in DB is always in the same format as given in the question, you can try splitting it. I have modified my code for splitting as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) :

```
 $date_day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($res0['dateInit']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select only date:

```
SELECT *, DATE(dateInit) FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo date("l");
```

// Prints something like: Monday

[Refer Here for mode details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)